# SSRS - Issue with Cascading Parameters Selection Refresh

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have cascading parameter that contains list of employees that produced reports for a certain date period. The parameter Employees is multi-select list and it's cascading parameter, i.e. depends on Beginning & Ending date parameters, so only employees that were active in this period will be displayed in the dropdown.

Here is the issue - when I modify dates to a longer period, my Employee list expands (so refresh happens correctly), but among all employees only those are selected, which were part of previous list, before changing beginning/ending date parameters. I need Employee list always to be SELECT ALL by default. SELECT ALL option does appear in the list, but it's not being selected after the refresh.

This SELECT ALL requirement is important as users may run report assuming all employees are selected, which in fact will not be the case, so current functionality is very misleading.

For your knowledge, default values for the Employee list are the same as Available values - getting list of employees from DB query based on period specified.

Appreciate your help on this matter.

Comment: As far as I remember, there is a *"bug"* with default values only being set once when date pickers are used. It sounds like you have encountered this 'feature'

Comment: Microsoft calls this a feature that "Works as Designed." I think the trick is to add the dates to the Parameter VALUE and then use the Label as the actual parameter values.